# Derivative of vector field on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, vector-bundles, vector-fields, tangent-bundle

Given two vector fields on a surface $v,w:S \subset \Bbb R^m \rightarrow T(S)$ my book defines the derivative of $v$ with respect to $w$ as 
$$\nabla_w v = (w(v_1),...,w(v_m))$$
where $(v_1,...,v_m)$ is the coordinate representation of $v$ with respect to the standard basis $\{ (\partial_{y_j})_p\}_{j=1}^m$ of the tangent space $T_p(S)$ for very $p \in S$.

These $v_i$ are functions from $S$ to $\Bbb R$ so you can apply to them the tangent vector $w_p$. So far so good.

Later though, considering a parametrization $x:U \subseteq \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow S$ it defines $x_u = \partial_u x$ and $x_v = \partial_v x$ for every $(u,v) \in U$. I consider these vector fields as the differential of $x$, i.e. the coordinates for the pushforward $(x_*)_{(u,v)}:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$.

Now take $x_u$. Being a vector field on $S$ we can compute $\nabla_{x_u} v$ and the book notes:

$$\nabla_{x_u} v = (\partial_u v_1,...,\partial_u v_m)$$
from which $\nabla_{x_u} x_u = x_{uu}$.
I think this doesn't make sense: as I said before $v_i:S \subset \Bbb R^m \rightarrow \Bbb R$, so you can't take their derivative in $\Bbb R^2$.
The second equality might be adjusted writing $\nabla_{\partial_u} x_u = x_{uu}$ since $x_u:U \rightarrow T(S) \cong \Bbb R^m$, and so is $\partial_u$.
Am I right?

Comment: Note this: your $x_u$ and your $\partial_u$ are actually the same (local) vector field (it is none other than the definition of coordinate vector fields!). Moreover, you can differentiate the $v_i$ functions, as they are local functions (hence actually $v_i\colon U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @AlessioDiLorenzo the way I understand it $x_u$ is a section of $T(S)$, while $\partial_u$ is a section of $T(U)$, so the first acts on functions defined on $S$, while the latter on functions defined on $U$. Since the components of $x_u$ are functions from $U$ I think that you can't derive them with respect to $x_u$.

Comment: Ok, now I think I am getting it a little better: $x_u$ and $\partial_u$ are not precisely the same, but you got $x_*\partial_u=x_u$. The main point here is that since taking (covariant) derivatives is a local issue, you may swap your vector field $x_u$ with its coordinate representation; hence $\nabla_{x_u}x_u=\bar{\nabla}_{\partial_u}x_u$, where $\bar{\nabla}$ is the pull-back connection induced on $U$ (look up Riemannian Geometry by Gallot, Theorem 3.28). By your definition of $\nabla$, you cannot have $\nabla_{\partial_u}x_u$ (since, as you said, $\partial_u\in\Gamma(T_U)$).

Comment: Anyway, in your very definition you apply the vector field $w\in\Gamma(T_S)$ to $v_i\colon S\to\mathbb{R}$, so I suppose that is not a big problem: you just need to do that locally (the formalisation of this is the concept of Lie derivative: $w\cdot v_i := \mathfrak{L}_w(v_i)$)

Comment: @AlessioDiLorenzo yes man the more I look into it the more I think that every vector field is pulled back on $U$ before its derivative is taken. Thanks a lot for your time, I'll look up your references as soon as I got more time. See you around :)